# How to add my snap-in to MMC

Tags: c#, windows-7, mmc

I'm dveloping simple C# application under Windows 7 as an span-in to mmc as in this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692759(VS.85).aspx

After adding the dll to GAC I used installutil.exe to install the snap-in
but I couldn't find it in add/remove snap-ins

please help

Comment: Show the log from the invocation of installutil.   Also, show the code for your snap-in, specifically the classes that are decorated with the `RunInstaller` attribute and the `SnapInSettings` attribute.

Comment: i found this text inside InstallLog 

"No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the <dll path> assembly.
Remove InstallState file because there are no installers."

about the classes i used the same sample in the link i produced

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the [RunInstallerAttribute(true)] declaration at the top of the installer class, and make sure that the installer class is public

Answer (score -1):

IF your App is 32bit then use

```
mmc /32
```

else

```
mmc
```

if your app is 64bit